# ¿Cómo encontrar con JavaScript el índice, o sea la posición de un número, sin utilizar indexOf?

Tags: javascript

Cordial saludo, será que me pueden brindar una mano para entenderlo, no logro estructurar el código. Aunque diseñé uno parecido en Node y me salió bien:

```
var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] === 4) { console.log(i)}

// la respuesta me dio indice 2 así que está bien en lo que hice como ejemplo con node
```

pero en este ejercicio no me sale. Agradezco una guía.

```
function index() {
  // Escribi una función encontraIndex en el prototipo de Arrays,
  // que recibe un elemento.
  // La function tiene que devolver el indice (index) del primer elemento que coincida con el pasado como parametro dentro del array.
  // Si el elemento se repite dentro del Array, este devuelve el indice del Primer elemento.
  // Si no existe ese elemento la funcion debe devolver -1
  // NO USAR LA FUNCION indexOf DE LOS ARREGLOS.
  // ej:
  // var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]
  // numeros.encontraIndex(4) debe devolver 2.
  // ya que el numero 4 se encuentra en la posicion 2 dentro del array.
  // numeros.encontraIndex(23) debe devolver -1 ya que ese elemento no existe en ese array.

  // Tu código aca:
  numeros.encontraIndex = function(){

  for (var i = 0; i <= arguments; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] === arguments) { return i}
    
  }
}
return -1; 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás usando mal `arguments`. Además no necesitas usarlo:

```js
function encuentraIndex(array, elemento) {
  for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if (array[i] === elemento) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
const miArray = [2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9];
let index = encuentraIndex(miArray, 5);
console.log('En la posición', index);
```

El uso de `arguments` es útil cuando tienes una función que puede recibir un número indeterminado de parámetros. Todos los parámetros se guardan en una colección similar a un Array:

```js
function test() {
  console.log('He recibido', arguments.length, 'parámetros');
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     console.log('El parametro', i+1,'es',arguments[i]);
  }
}

test();
test(1)
test(1,2,3, 'Hola mundo','último parámetro');
```

Answer (score 3):

Como aporte a la respuesta. El objeto `Array` en Javascript tiene una metodo llamada `findIndex`, que realiza lo mismo que buscas aunque en vez de pasarle el numero a buscar, se le entrega una `callback` a resolver. cuando esta es verdadera retorna el `indice`, cuando no hay coincidencias retornara `-1`.

Ejemplo:

```
[5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4].findIndex((n) => n === 23) // retorna -1

[5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4].findIndex((n) => n === 4) // retorna 2
```

La ventaja que entrega `findIndex` es que no solo se limita a buscar el elemento exacto sino que puedes buscar mayor que o el primero diferente.

Dejo algo de documentación para que lo revises [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function(numero) {
let pos =[];
for (let i = 0 ; i < this.length; i++){
  if(numero === this[i]){
    pos.push(i);
  }
}
if(pos.length>0){
  return pos[0];
}
return -1
```

}
}

Comment: _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ No olvides explicar _qué hace este código_. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.